# How to return html text variable in react and print as html?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> Function 1 Which returns JSON array.

```
function allPlans()
{
    var all_plans = {
            'Stock Card Views' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Portfolio Creation' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Transactions In A Portfolio' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Advance Filter':{
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"}                            
            },
            'Stock Card Requests' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Premium Posrfolio Access' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Portfolio"}                            
            },
            'Investment Pick' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Per Month"}                            
            },
        }

    return all_plans;
}
```

> Function 2: Used Above function in below function

```
function renderPlansArray()
{

    var all_plans = allPlans();
    var rowclass = true;

    var htmltext = "";
    for(var PlanName in all_plans) 
    {

        console.log(plan_item_gray);
        if (props.planname == 'free')
        {

            if(rowclass == true)
            {
                rowclass = false;
                htmltext += <div className={plan_item_gray}>all_plans[PlanName]['free']['plantext']</div>;
            }
            else
            {
                rowclass = true;
                htmltext += <div className={plan_item}>all_plans[PlanName]['free']['plantext']</div>;
            }


        }

    }

    return(htmltext);

}
```

In the above function, I have generated an HTML Text in `htmltext` variable and return. But when I return same like above this will return [object Object] and when I convert into a string then it will print HTML text as it is.

I want to return this variable as HTML.

I have called above function in another function to render HTML like below.

```
return (<div className={plan_column}>
   {renderPlansArray()}
</div>)
```

> It is returning:

[image]

> AND

[image]

> I need HTML LIKE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `React` you don't have to mess with HTML stuff.
You can render your data by using `React.Components`. Below I created snippet to show how it can be done.

I hope it will help.

```js
function allPlans()
{
    var all_plans = {
            'Stock Card Views' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"5 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Portfolio Creation' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Transactions In A Portfolio' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Unlimited"}                            
            },
            'Advance Filter':{
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"Full Access"}                            
            },
            'Stock Card Requests' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"3 Per Month"}                            
            },
            'Premium Posrfolio Access' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Portfolio"}                            
            },
            'Investment Pick' : {
                'free':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'premium':{status:true,plantext:"-"},
                'vip':{status:true,plantext:"1 Per Month"}                            
            },
        }

    return all_plans;
}

const Column = ({data}) => (
  <ul>
    {data.map(option => (
      <li key={option.title}>
        {option.title}: {option.text}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

const App = () => {
  const options = allPlans();
  const plansMap = Object.keys(options).reduce((acc, title) => {
    const plans = options[title];
    
    Object.keys(plans).forEach(plan => {
      if (!acc[plan]) {
        acc[plan] = [];
      }
    
      acc[plan].push({
        title,
        status: plans[plan].status,
        text: plans[plan].plantext
      })
    });
    
    return acc;
  }, {})
  
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(plansMap).map(plan => (
        <div key={plan}>
          <h3>{plan}</h3>
          <Column data={plansMap[plan]} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't include styling stuff, but this question is not about it.

Comment: I tried your code by changing as per my requirement, but it showing records twice in each column.

Comment: Feel free to modify `reduce` function to get an appropriate data structure.

Comment: used map instead of reduce but still showing record twice. :(

Comment: @Prashant Patil, I am glad that it has helped.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to set HTML directly you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` something like:

```
someHtml = '<div><strong>blablabla<strong><p>another blbla</p/></div>'


return(<div className="Container" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 
            someHtml}}></div>)
```

However, this is not the way you are supposed to work with `jsx` & react. A better approach will be to use `React.components` and render them.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly.. but as you said another approach to use React.components, I'm trying that way.. Thanks :)